# How to create database table dynamically and insert data selected by query

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

I'm working on website where I need to find rank of user on the basis of score. Earlier I'm calculating the score and rank of user by sql query .

```
select * from (
    select
        usrid,
        ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER(ORDER BY (count(*)+sum(sup)+sum(opp)+sum(visited)*0.3) DESC) AS rank,
        (count(*)+sum(sup)+sum(opp)+sum(visited)*0.3 ) As score
    from [DB_].[dbo].[dsas]
    group by usrid) as cash
where usrid=@userid
```

Please don't concentrate more on query because this is only to explain how I select data.

Problem: Now I can't use above query because every time I use rank it need to select rank from `dsas` table and data of `dsas` table is increasing day by day and slows down my website.

What I need is select data by above query and insert in another table named as score. Can we do anything like this?

Answer (score 2):

A better solution is to either include `score` as a field in your user table or have a separate table for scores.  Any time you add new `sup`, `opp`, or `visited` data for a user, also recalculate their score at that time.

Then to get the highest ranking users, you will be able to perform a very simple `select` statement, ordering by score descending, and only fetching the number of rows you want.  It will be very fast.

Comment: yeah i m thinking about that only . My problem is that how to insert data  dynamically of 1000 user's selected by above query .

Comment: @chetanSaini, you could add an extra query to update score at each location that changes `sup`,`opp`, and `visited`. Or you could add a trigger to the database that will do that automatically.

Comment: first we have to create table with fields usrid and score . After that insert all user data then we have to take step suggested by you. So our first priority is to create table with all user data .